# Sonos Music API implementation “Unable to browse music” error on first request

Tags: sonos

In our implementation of the Sonos Music API, im running into an issue which with requesting album containers. the first time an album is requested, it always fails with the message "Unable to browse music". if you then press back, and open the same album again, it opens just fine and shows the track listing and album details.

I did check if there are any differences in the response from our server between the first and second request, but there is no difference. Nor are there any timing differences (the request loads (both times) in under 200ms on my developer station).

I also used SoapUI to verify that the Soap server returns proper data, and it validates without any errors.

The test suite also returns no errors or warnings.

Is there a way to see the actual error? or any suggestions on how to approach this?

a typical request looks like:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header>
      <credentials xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
         <sessionId>f42257a8-c046-11e6-82d0-d4bed9ed478a</sessionId>
         <deviceId>xx-xx-00-00-00-00:x</deviceId>
         <deviceProvider>Sonos</deviceProvider>
      </credentials>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <getMetadata xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
         <id>album:112779295</id>
         <index>0</index>
         <count>30</count>
      </getMetadata>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

and response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:getMetadataResponse>
         <ns1:getMetadataResult>
            <ns1:index>0</ns1:index>
            <ns1:count>13</ns1:count>
            <ns1:total>13</ns1:total>
            <ns1:mediaCollection>
               <ns1:id>album:112779295</ns1:id>
               <ns1:itemType>album</ns1:itemType>
               <ns1:displayType>list</ns1:displayType>
               <ns1:title>Kenny B - Kenny B</ns1:title>
               <ns1:summary>blop</ns1:summary>
               <ns1:isFavorite>true</ns1:isFavorite>
               <ns1:language>NL</ns1:language>
               <ns1:country>NL</ns1:country>
               <ns1:genreId>genre:1</ns1:genreId>
               <ns1:genre>Nederlands</ns1:genre>
               <ns1:twitterId/>
               <ns1:liveNow>false</ns1:liveNow>
               <ns1:onDemand>true</ns1:onDemand>
               <ns1:artist>Kenny B</ns1:artist>
               <ns1:artistId>artist:1425214</ns1:artistId>
               <ns1:canScroll>true</ns1:canScroll>
               <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
               <ns1:canEnumerate>true</ns1:canEnumerate>
               <ns1:canAddToFavorites>true</ns1:canAddToFavorites>
               <ns1:containsFavorite>false</ns1:containsFavorite>
               <ns1:canCache>false</ns1:canCache>
               <ns1:canSkip>false</ns1:canSkip>
               <ns1:albumArtURI>https://mobile.unplug.de/artwork.php?id=112779295&amp;w=300</ns1:albumArtURI>
               <ns1:authRequired>false</ns1:authRequired>
               <ns1:homogeneous>false</ns1:homogeneous>
               <ns1:canAddToFavorite>true</ns1:canAddToFavorite>
            </ns1:mediaCollection>
            <ns1:mediaMetadata>
               <ns1:id>track:610294458</ns1:id>
               <ns1:itemType>track</ns1:itemType>
               <ns1:displayType>List</ns1:displayType>
               <ns1:title>Alleen Jij</ns1:title>
               <ns1:mimeType>application/x-mpegURL</ns1:mimeType>
               <ns1:trackMetadata>
                  <ns1:artistId>artist:1425214</ns1:artistId>
                  <ns1:artist>Kenny B</ns1:artist>
                  <ns1:albumId>album:112779295</ns1:albumId>
                  <ns1:albumArtistId>artist:1425214</ns1:albumArtistId>
                  <ns1:duration>223</ns1:duration>
                  <ns1:rating>1</ns1:rating>
                  <ns1:albumArtURI>https://mobile.unplug.de/artwork.php?id=112779295&amp;w=300</ns1:albumArtURI>
                  <ns1:trackNumber>1</ns1:trackNumber>
                  <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
                  <ns1:canSkip>true</ns1:canSkip>
                  <ns1:canAddToFavorites>true</ns1:canAddToFavorites>
               </ns1:trackMetadata>
            </ns1:mediaMetadata>
            <ns1:mediaMetadata>
               <ns1:id>track:610294459</ns1:id>
               <ns1:itemType>track</ns1:itemType>
               <ns1:displayType>List</ns1:displayType>
               <ns1:title>Als Je Gaat</ns1:title>
               <ns1:mimeType>application/x-mpegURL</ns1:mimeType>
               <ns1:trackMetadata>
                  <ns1:artistId>artist:1425214</ns1:artistId>
                  <ns1:artist>Kenny B</ns1:artist>
                  <ns1:albumId>album:112779295</ns1:albumId>
                  <ns1:albumArtistId>artist:1425214</ns1:albumArtistId>
                  <ns1:duration>191</ns1:duration>
                  <ns1:rating>1</ns1:rating>
                  <ns1:albumArtURI>https://mobile.unplug.de/artwork.php?id=112779295&amp;w=300</ns1:albumArtURI>
                  <ns1:trackNumber>2</ns1:trackNumber>
                  <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
                  <ns1:canSkip>true</ns1:canSkip>
                  <ns1:canAddToFavorites>true</ns1:canAddToFavorites>
               </ns1:trackMetadata>
            </ns1:mediaMetadata>
            ...
         </ns1:getMetadataResult>
      </ns1:getMetadataResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently this is caused when there is a mediaCollection in the response. after a lot of debugging and trying, i found that it was resolved by simply removing this from the response.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too, I'm not certain what causes it, but it stopped once I put a LIMIT at the end of my SQL query to get the tracks, as long as the limit was <= 99 (the default number of items Sonos requests in the getMetadata post). I expect it's something to do with returning more items than Sonos expects.